# Difference between the Wasserstein metric, mallows metric and Earth mover's distance

Tags: distance, metric, wasserstein

I'm really confused, is there a **difference** between the **Wasserstein metric, mallows metric and Earth mover's distance**?
If yes What is it?

Thank you

Comment: Wasserstein's metric and earth mover's distance are two names for the  same concept.

Comment: Thank you. I heard that the wasserstein metric is "a natural extension of the euclidean metric" ? I don't really get why?

Comment: @learneRS This video helped me understand the general idea behind it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymWDGzpQdls